# how to add Amenities option for finding special facilities like cafeteria, washrooms etc. in react native maps

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, maps, react-native-navigation, react-native-maps

buttons which has cafeteria or washroom logos, when clicked should take to the nearest cafeteria or nearest washroom respectively.
Its for a custom campus map.
stuck here for a long time.
Any idea how I could get this?

Comment: Have you checked custom markers - https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps#rendering-a-marker-with-a-custom-view

Comment: I need a multiple buttons when clicked should generate path for nearest washroom or cafe near by

Comment: A button when i click takes me to nearest washroom or cafe. Not in google maps but in a custom map.